# Show that a multivariate polynomial must be $\pm 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Suppose $f,r,s \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ satisfy $rf = x$ and $sf = y.$ Show that $f= \pm 1.$

> Show that if $p,f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ are such that $pf = 2, f \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2\}.$

I tried explicitly multiplying these polynomials out, but it seems difficult to show that $f = \pm 1$ solely from using this definition. Intuitively, it seems to hold because $x$ and $y$ are "independent" of each other. It's clearly possible if $f = \pm 1,$ but I need to show that if $f \neq \pm 1$, it's impossible to find polynomials $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ so that $rf = x$ and $sf = y.$ So suppose $f\neq \pm 1.$ I claim that for every polynomial $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y], rf \neq x$ or $sf \neq y.$ However, I'm not sure how to find a contradiction if $rf = x$ and $sf = y.$

> After another attempt, I considered plugging in various values. In particular, setting $x=1,$ we get that $rf_{x=1}$ is a polynomial in $y$ with degree $0$, so both are constant polynomials in $y$ that multiply to $1$. Similarly, setting $y=1$ on both sides of the equation $sf=y,$ we see that $s$ and $f$ are constants in terms of $x$ and multiply to $1$. Hence $f = \pm 1.$

For the second part, don't I just need to show that if $\mathbb{K}$ is a field and $f, p\in \mathbb{K}[x],$ then $\deg(fp) = \deg(f) + \deg(p)$? Then I can just take the field $\mathbb{R}$ and use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[x]\subseteq \mathbb{R}[x]$ to get that $p$ and $f$ must be constants and hence divide $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $R$ is a domain, the "total degree" of $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_\alpha c_\alpha x^\alpha$ in the multivariate polynomial ring $R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is $\deg f = \max\{\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n : c_\alpha \neq 0\}$. It is undefined when $f=0$. It satisfies $\deg fg = \deg f + \deg g$.

Your constraints on $f$ say that it has total degree at most $1$. Getting that it is $\pm 1$ from there is quite straightforward. This is an instance where trying to make some counterexamples by hand probably would guide you to correct abstract arguments.

Comment: how would I prove the inequality involving "total degree"? I thought of using it, but didn't mention it because I didn't know how to prove it. Isn't my alternative approach of substituting $x=1$ and then $y=1$ and getting a single variable polynomial and then using the fact that for single variable polynomials, $\deg(fg) = \deg(f)+\deg(g)$ (a much less general result that's much easier to prove in my opinion) correct? If it's wrong, could you explain why?

Comment: @Alfred Write $f = \sum_{i \geq 0} f_i$ where $f_i$ consists of all $\alpha$ with $\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n = i$. Do the same with $g$. Now use the usual one-variable argument: $f_i g_j$ with $i=\deg f, j=\deg g$ is the only contribution to the top-most component of $fg$, which is non-zero since $f_i, g_i$ are non-zero elements of a domain.